# Is it possible to Filter entry types via the URL?

Tags: entry-type, best-practice

I'm wondering if it's possible to dynamically filter a section list by entry type based on a url segment?

I'm hoping to avoid assigning a category to every entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Pass the entry type handle to a segment and access that segment using the `craft.request` [`getSegment()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getSegment) method. Use this segment variable with the `craft.entries` [`.type()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#type) method to fetch only the entries of the given type. The example below assumes your entry type handle is in segment 2.

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages').type(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Would I need to set up a route in order to tell craft to use the template from the first segment? When I add another segment to the url I get a 404 error.

Comment: Great point. If the URL that loads the template is tied to a Single or Section entry, yes, you should define a route.